# Create a bootable physical server from the O/S within a VM

Tags: vmware-player, v2p

I have a VMWare Ubuntu VM created with VMWare player. Is there any way to install the Ubuntu system that is in the VM onto a physical server? In other words I want the server to boot with the exact same system and as is currently in the VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of doing this is to create an image of the VMWare machine with software like clonezilla or ghost and then write that image to a physical disk.  This should work, but be prepared to do some cursory driver/config maintenance once the image is written.

Comment: You might also want to look into using VMware's [ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor/index.html) product.  You should be able to convert the VM using [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) and then you can more easily move it to another server if need be.

Comment: @Scott Warren  Thank you for the ESXi information.  I was not aware that their migration software was free.